# Error while reading CSV file using Apache POI

Tags: apache-poi

I am trying to read a CSV file from a local drive using the Apache PoI API.

```
    FileInputStream fInputStream = new FileInputStream(inputName);
    Workbook workBook = WorkbookFactory.create(fInputStream);
```

1. When I try to read a CSV file, which is created in Windows, the API reads it perfectly.
2. Whereas, when I have the CSV file(which is DOWNLOADED from an UNIX environment) and read it in windows environment, I get the below exception.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:81)

Can somebody throw some inputs on this behavior.

Comment: POI is for reading **Excel** files. For CSV files there are much better alternatives

Comment: Apache POI only supports reading Excel `.xls` and `.xlsx` files, [as explained on the website](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/). It explicitly does not support CSV files

Comment: But I was able to read the csv file as well. The issue does not happen if the CSV file is created in Windows file system and read from the local drive.

I get the above exception, only when the CSV file is created and downloaed from an UNIX environment and read in the Windows Environment. 

Does it have to be anything to do like 'dos2unix' (which we do it from Windows -> Unix scenario). Do we need to see if there is any other preprocessing needs to be done.